# How Would One Unit Test an HtmlHelper Which Actually Uses the helper in the Extension Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, moq

I've spent the better half of this afternoon trying to figure out how to mock (using MOQ) up the relevant bits and pieces to unit test the following HtmlHelper, which users the UrlHelper class to create img tags:

```
    public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        // Instantiate a UrlHelper
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        // Create tag builder
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");

        // Create valid id
        builder.GenerateId(id);

        // Add attributes
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", urlHelper.Content(url));
        builder.MergeAttribute("alt", alternateText);
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

        // Render tag
        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
```

Has anyone solved this problem already in their work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test the end result. If you know that you helper should rerurn something like, lets say:

```
<img src="test.jpg" id="testId" alt="something" />
```

Then your Assertion should be by comparing this string against the actual result. You should not care whether it is using helper internally itself or not.

Comment: You can't do it as you suggest. How would you create the HtmlHelper in your unit test? You don't have access to the runtime environment of the MVC framework, which gives you the @Html helper property. You can't just "new one up". And you can't just call the method statically, as it is an extension method which uses the object which it is extending. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @onefootswill, the problem that you have is the UrlHelper in your code. With that class you cannot do the testing. What you should do is to generate the url when you pass it to your helper and not inside of your helper.

Comment: I think you are correct. Whilst I do like having the UrlHelper inside the extension method, it's not test-friendly code. I will stick with it. I know the helper works. It doesn't need a test. I want to encapsulate the UrlHepler so the tilda-prefixed string is passed in.

Comment: For these kind of situations you could use Microsoft Fakes Framework which allows Shims. I personally don't like this because it kind of blinds you from seeing where you code is not following single responsibility principle. I'm glad that I could have helped at least a bit.

Answer (score 1):

When I run into .NET types which are not unit test friendly I usually write my own interface (with only the methods that I need) and a shim class implementing the interface which just forwards method/property calls to the original class. The shim is testable by inspection.

Then I write all of the code that I need to unit test against this interface (so I depend on abstractions, not concretions). This includes extension methods, which extend the interface rather than the original concrete type. In this respect, testing extension methods is as easy as `new Mock<IHtmlHelper>() ...` - you can make `IHtmlHelper` do anything you like because you have total control of its behaviour in your unit tests.

Typing out the interface and the shim is a little bit tedious for classes with larger interfaces, but mostly I find the overhead is very low. It also means that I end up doing fewer weird tricks to make things testable, so my code is more consistent and easy to follow (dependencies are always injected the same way, tests are always written the same way).

I think the point that Husein Roncevic is making is that you should be testing the *clients* of `HtmlHelper` in terms of observable state rather than behaviour. In other words, the unit tests for the client code should not be aware of which methods were called (extension methods or otherwise). It sounds like you want to unit test the extension method itself, which is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Comment: That's correct. I want to test the extension method itself. It's probably not a big deal. I know it works,and I don't do TDD. But I do write unit tests and I do like to get as much coverage as possible.